# Firefox issue with position absolute inside an item with display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have 3 li's that I am trying to line up horizontally and then position a span inside each of the li's.

The spans get positioned correctly in Chrome but are well outside the boundary of the li's in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/brendan_rice/mPnCh/1/

Can anyone help please?

```
<div id="blank-slate-steps">
   <ul>
      <li class="first">
         <h3><em>Step 1</em>Create Something</h3>
         <p>Once you have created Something Else you can Create Final Thing</p>
         <span></span>
      </li>
      <li class="second">
         <h3><em>Step 2</em>Create Something Else</h3>
         <p>Once you have created Something Else you can Create Final Thing</p>
         <span></span>
      </li>
      <li class="third">
         <h3><em>Step 3</em>Create Final Thing</h3>
         <p>Once you have created Something Else you can Create Final Thing</p>
         <span></span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
body{
padding-top: 300px;
}
#blank-slate-steps {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: OpenSansCondensedBold,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#blank-slate-steps li {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
#blank-slate-steps h3 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}
#blank-slate-steps h3 em {
    color: #878787;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
#blank-slate-steps li.second span {
    background: red url("../images/sprite/icons-grey-38.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -56px transparent;
    height: 37px;
    width: 36px;
}
#blank-slate-steps span {
background-color: red;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

​

Comment: FWIW: consider voting for fixing this [bug 803735](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=803735) in Mozilla's bug-tracker.

Comment: Consider also voting for fixing bug 63895 (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895), duplicate of which was the bug mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use position relative for blank-slate-steps div.

```
#blank-slate-steps {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: OpenSansCondensedBold,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I had an issue similar to Burt, and this was the solution that worked (you know, but for my div classes)!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've made it work, you can do it like this : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPnCh/2/)

Explanation: What I did was, I used `position: relative;` for `#blank-slate-steps` and than used `position: relative;` again for `div` and wrapped the `<li>` content inside it

HTML

```
<div id="blank-slate-steps">
   <ul>
      <li class="first">
          <div style="position: relative;">
         <h3><em>Step 1</em>Create Something</h3>
         <p>Once you have created Something Else you can Create Final Thing</p>
         <span></span>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="second">
          <div style="position: relative;">
         <h3><em>Step 2</em>Create Something Else</h3>
         <p>Once you have created Something Else you can Create Final Thing</p>
         <span></span>
           </div>
      </li>
      <li class="third">
          <div style="position: relative;">
         <h3><em>Step 3</em>Create Final Thing</h3>
         <p>Once you have created Something Else you can Create Final Thing</p>
         <span></span>
          </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    padding-top: 300px;
}
#blank-slate-steps {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: OpenSansCondensedBold,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#blank-slate-steps li {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 300px;
}
#blank-slate-steps h3 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}
#blank-slate-steps h3 em {
    color: #878787;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
#blank-slate-steps li.second span {
    background: red url("../images/sprite/icons-grey-38.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -56px transparent;
    height: 37px;
    width: 36px;
}
#blank-slate-steps span {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your span in first like that:

```
<li class="second">
     <span></span>
     <h3><em>Step 2</em>Create Something Else</h3>
     <p>Once you have created Something Else you can Create Final Thing</p>
  </li>
```

and put the span in `position:relative` and `float:left`